# Can't play m3u8 file online in Samsung device on Android

Tags: android, m3u8

I have a online radio  Android App, that is trying to play url http://mixlr.com/broadcasts/1d822029ee26f741ddb7be0645c3dcc0/playlist.m3u8. We are internally using MediaPlayer and code is as usual.Everything is fine but it cannot play on certain devices like Samsung,Intex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our finding at http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html says the Android Medi Framework is only  limited to certain file formats.

There is a rich media client for playing wide variety of media formats Vitamio at https://www.vitamio.org/en/

Solved the issue with Vitamio.